# Django test not returning proper status code

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I was writing some tests for the authentication of my website to check to see if a user already exists a particular username or not. In my main code, it is supposed to return a status code of 409 and I tried to use that status code to assert the status code that I get from my response from the tests but the tests always give me a status code 200.

In short, I can't get the response to have a status code of anything other than 200 while running tests, however when I try using it from the manage.py shell it works as expected.

Here's the view:

```
views.py

def sign_up(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.POST["username"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).count() != 0:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                                 "An account already exists with that username")

            return render(request, "authentication/sign_up.html", status=409)

    else:
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=username, email=email, password=password)
        user.save()

    return render(request, "authentication/sign_up.html")
```

Here's the test file.

```
class SignUpTests(TestCase):

    def test_account_with_username_already_exists(self):

        response = self.client.post(reverse("authentication:sign_up"), {
            "username": "yasa.zaheen",
            "email": "yasazaheen728@gmail.com",
            "password": "12345678"
        })

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 409)
```

Here is the assertion error:

```
D:\Aurora\aurora>manage.py test  
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_account_with_username_already_exists (authentication.tests.SignUpTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\Aurora\aurora\authentication\tests.py", line 34, in test_account_with_username_already_exists
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 409)
AssertionError: 200 != 409

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.410s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Here's what I get if I do it from the shell:

```
D:\Aurora\aurora>manage.py shell
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on    win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.post("/auth/sign_up/", {"username":"yasa.zaheen","email":"yasazaheen@gmail.com","password":"1234"}) 
2
Conflict: /auth/sign_up/ 
>>> response.status_code
409
>>> ^Z

now exiting InteractiveConsole..
```

Comment: It means that the username is not yet been taken. Note that tests run on a *seperate* database, so items in your database, will not be available in the database for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Django runs tests in a *seperate* database, this to avoid introducing data in the real database. As a result an email address that has been taken in your main database, has no record in the test database.

You thus will need to add a record first, for example with:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class SignUpTests(TestCase):

    def test_account_with_username_already_exists(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.objects.create_user(username='yasa.zaheen', password='54321')
        response = self.client.post(reverse('authentication:sign_up'), {
            'username': 'yasa.zaheen',
            'email': 'yasazaheen728@gmail.com',
            'password': '12345678'
        })

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 409)
```

I would also advise to work with a Django form instead of processing the `request.POST` data manually. Forms remove a lot of boilerplate code, collect all errors (so not only the first one), and make it more convenient to validate, clean and store data.

Comment: Thanks man that worked! I had another question, why do we have to use get_user_model() instead of just importing User from django.contrib.auth.models?

Comment: @YasaZaheen: because if you later change the user model do some other model,  it will work with that new user model. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model for best practices when working with the user model.